# Trouble Adding Ports (8000 and 8090) to WampServer

Tags: apache, port, wamp

I'm encountering an issue while trying to add ports 8000 and 8090 to my WampServer configuration. Despite my efforts, these ports don't seem to be functioning as expected.

**Configuration and Steps Taken:**

1. I've made the following modifications to my httpd.conf file:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:86
Listen [::0]:86
Listen 0.0.0.0:70
Listen [::0]:70
Listen 0.0.0.0:88
Listen [::0]:88
Listen 0.0.0.0:8000
Listen [::0]:8000
Listen 0.0.0.0:8090
Listen [::0]:8090
```

2. I've also updated my Virtual Host definitions in httpd-vhosts.conf
   to include these ports.

**Additional Information:**

- Am on Windows 11.
- I'm using WampServer version 3.3.0.
- I've checked for port availability and confirmed that ports 8000 and
  8090 are not in use by other applications.
- I've also verified that there are no conflicts with Listen directives
  in other parts of the Apache configuration.
- The other working ports 70, 86 and 88 were added some months ago.
- I'm not seeing any error messages in the Apache error logs.

**Problem Description:**

When I attempt to access http://localhost:8000 or http://localhost:8090 in my web browser, I receive an "Unable to connect" message.

When I used **telnet** to check if the ports

```
telnet localhost 8000
```

```
telnet localhost 8090
```

These are the responses

```
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 8000: Connect failed


Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 8090: Connect failed
```

How do I resolve this.

Comment: Have you opened that ports on Window Firewall?